# Binding to NSTextField Cell not working, edited value resets to default

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstablecolumn, nstableviewcell

I'm working on a Core Data document application that dynamically creates `NSTableColumns`. The data cell type may be a checkbox, slider, etc. Programmatically binding to all cell types works, except for `NSTextFieldCell`.

All `NSTextFieldCells` fail to bind, and after editing they return to their default value. This happens no matter if they're binding to a string, a number (with an `NSNumberFormatter` applied), or a date (`NSDateFormatter` applied). I'm using the following format to do all bindings:

```
NSDictionary *textFieldOpts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"YES", NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption, @"YES", NSValidatesImmediatelyBindingOption, nil];
[aCell bind:@"value" toObject:[[entryAC arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] withKeyPath:@"numberData" options:textFieldOpts];
```

Again, these statements work if the cell type is anything but an `NSTextFieldCell`.

I threw in an `-observeValueForKeyPath` method to log when the value changes... and for other cell types (`NSSliderCell` for instance) I can see the value changing, but with the `NSTextFieldCell`, it never, ever updates.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to implement the NSTableView data source method setObjectValue to manually get the change from the NSTableView (View) and then manually set the data in the array controller (Model) similar to the code below:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    [[[entryAC arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:rowIndex] setValue:(NSNumber *)anObject forKey:@"numberData"];
}
```

For some reason, the bindings to NSTextFieldCells, when set programmatically on a cell-by-cell basis, only work one way: to display the data only. Personally I would classify this as a bug...